# How to write Tire query where an association_id is nil or certain value?

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I have a Lesson model that belongs_to Account.

Public lessons have a nil account_id.

Private lessons have a value in account_id.

How do I write a search for Lesson for some search term present in public and private Lessons?

```
LessonContentBlock.search(
  :load => true, 
  :page => (params[:page] || 1)
  ) do
  query do
    boolean do
      should { string q }
      filter :missing => { :field => 'account_id' }
      should { string "account_id:#{a.id}" }
    end
  end
end
```

I've also tried this:

```
LessonContentBlock.search(
  :load => true, 
  :page => (params[:page] || 1)
  ) do
  query { string q }
  filter :missing, :field => 'account_id'
  filter :term, :account_id => a.id
end
```

Comment: Your code refers to variable `a` that appears to be a *specific* account you are filtering by. Does this mean you are trying to find records that either belong to this single private account `a` or are public?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, then you want to do something like this:

```
LessonContentBlock.search(
    :load => true, 
    :page => (params[:page] || 1)
    ) do
  query { string q }
  filter :or, {:term => {:account_id => a.id}},
              {:missing => {:field => 'account_id'}}
end
```

I thought I knew how to solve this, but struggled getting it working myself. Eventually found a good example in Tire's test suite: http://git.io/v0PGBw.